# Why I can't connect to VPS after changing OS from CentOS to Ubuntu?

Tags: ssh

Recently, I've changed my VPS operating system from CentOS to Ubuntu. Unfortunately since then I can't connect to my VPS. The following message comes again and again (screenshot attached).
[image]
Why this is happening and how can I solve that?

Comment: err... did you added the key in the `known_hosts` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message tells you everything you need to know. You need to edit the file, `known_hosts` and remove the offending key that was added from the previous OS.

Each time you install a different distro a new set of public/private SSH keys is generated per the host.

#### Using an editor

I usually just open up the file in `vim` and go to the line number that's specified in the error message:

> Offending RSA key in /home/fahim/.ssh/known_hosts:1

The line number would be 1. Once in `vim`, go to line number 1, <kbd>:1</kbd> and then delete it, <kbd>dd</kbd>. Once done, save the file, <kbd>:w</kbd>.

#### Using ssh-keygen

You can also programmatically delete entries from the file, but be careful, it will remove all matches for IP and/or hostname, depending on which method you go for.

```
$ ssh-keygen -R <hostname or IP>
```

**NOTE:** If you look at the message it's telling you to run this type of command:

> remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/fahim/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 23.88.229.252

#### Example

Say I have this host named smurfy.

```
$ ssh-keygen -R smurfy
# Host smurfy found: line 139 type RSA
/home/saml/.ssh/known_hosts updated.
Original contents retained as /home/saml/.ssh/known_hosts.old
```

Here by not specifying the file with the `-f` switch, `ssh-keygen` will remove the entry from the default `known_hosts` file, which is the one located here, `/home/saml/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as SSH is concerned, the identity of a machine is its SSH private key. The SSH private key is one half of a key pair; the other half is a public key. The key pair is stored in two files, located at `/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key` and `/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub` (or similar locations, e.g. in the directory `/etc/ssh` or with `dsa` or `ecdsa` instead of `rsa`). The key pair is generated when you install the system.

When you log into that machine remotely, the SSH client needs to verify that you're connected to the right machine, and not to an impersonator who spies on your traffic. It can make this check if you have a copy of the public key on the client (such are the wonders of public-key cryptography). The first time you connect to a new remote host, SSH stores a copy of its public key in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

If you reinstall a machine, it's a new machine. Never mind the name: anyone can impersonate a name. But the private key is unique; after reinstalling, the machine has a different private key, it's not the same machine anymore. If you want to keep the same machine, you need to back up and restore the key pair.

When you log in to a remote machine, you specify its name, not its public key. The name you specify serves as a nickname for the “real” identity of the machine which is its public key. (Think of the key as the machine's DNA.) The `known_hosts` file is a database that maps nicknames to identities (public keys).

After the reinstallation, the machine has kept its nickname but changed its identity — or to put it another way there's a new machine with the same nickname. This is indistinguishable from an attacker trying to pass off as the legitimate machine. That's what the big scary warning is about.

Since the old machine doesn't exist anymore, you need to remove the reference to it from the `known_hosts` file. You do this with the command `ssh-keygen -R …` as indicated in the message from `ssh`. This command updated your `known_hosts` file so that SSH no longer knows about your nickname for the machine, so that you can reuse that nickname for another machine (which happens to have the same IP address, but isn't the same machine since its key pair is different).