# What elements affects the key pairs generated by ssh-keygen?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keygen

I use the `ssh-keygen -t rsa` to generate the RSA key pairs. I see that in the `id_rsa.pub` file, I see the username and the hostname.

But I want to know that what elements will affects the key pairs. For example, if I change the host ip, need I regenerate the key pairs? And the hostname? or even I reinstall the operating system?

When should I regenerate the key pairs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I can't connect to VPS after changing OS from CentOS to Ubuntu?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104323/why-i-cant-connect-to-vps-after-changing-os-from-centos-to-ubuntu)

Comment: I think it a little different to the question. At least, It didn't cover all my cases I think.

Comment: Yeah, it's slightly different question but Gille's answer covers most of the details that you have asked. But anyways welcome to U & L SE :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is randomly generated. There's nothing more special to its origin than that. Meaning that as long as only you hold the private key, there is no need to replace it.

In SSH, a user key is generally used to identify a combination of user & origin system. Meaning the key is not shared among users on the same system, or the same user on multiple systems.
Though this is not a technical limitation, as you can break either of these rules without issue. It's just good security practice.

In a public key (`id_rsa.pub`), the last field is a comment. The `ssh-keygen` command typically puts your username & hostname as the last field. This serves no purpose other than as a comment to identify the key. As for why it puts username & hostname, see the previous paragraph.

To directly answer your question, "When should I regenerate the key pairs?":
You should regenerate the key when the key has been compromised, and has potentially been obtained by someone else. At this time you should also revoke the previous public key from all remote systems which trust it (the `authorized_keys` file).
That is literally the only reason. If you reinstall the OS, change hostname, etc, you do not need to recreate the key. Though you can if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

From [rfc4716](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4716.txt) we know the user@hostname in `id_rsa.pub` is only a comment, it doesn't affect the key pairs contents.

I think username is one of the elements that affects the contents because I use two user to have the different key pairs on the same host :-)

Comment: and I think hostname and ip modification doesn't affect the key pairs contents.  But if you reinstall the os, you need to regenerate the key pairs.